# Make jquery off onclick if sortable occure

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to disable onclick if sortable event occure. I try to make off the onclick when sortable but the onclick still fire after the sorting end...

```
$("ol.example").on('click',function(){alert(1);});
$("ol.example").sortable({
  start: function(event, ui) { $("ol.example").off("click"); },
  stop: function(event, ui) { $("ol.example").off("click"); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial post, one can ignore this section, i am leaving it here just for audit.

I propose a workaround to your problem.

Basically, you do not want the click handler to run when the element is "sortable". We will take advantage of the class on sortable elements. class= "ui-sortable"

So, add a check in your click handler to check for the class "ui-sortable"

```
$("ol.example").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-sortable')){
        alert(1);
    }
});
```

However, this still may run into some race-conditions, let's get around that by introducing a 50ms delay with setTimeout()

```
$("ol.example").on('click',function(){
    var _self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(_self.hasClass('ui-sortable')){
            alert(1);
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

---

### EDIT: Here is a modified solution. Play with it on CodePen

https://codepen.io/ji_in_coding/pen/aazvGo?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<ol id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).addClass('ui-being-dragged');
  },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).removeClass('ui-being-dragged');
  }
});

$("#sortable>li").on('click',function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('ui-being-dragged')){
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: :( not fire alert on either case - sort or simple click

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make it easier to understand? point out exactly what you would like to achieve

Comment: i have an ordered list "<ol><li>..." and i need to do two separate things with <li>... 1. to sort if i drag up & down without to fire the onclick 2. to fire the onclick only if i click on element. The problem is if i sort also i fire the onclick since i need to click&hold the element and drag around... Your solution with setTimeout only delay the onclick if i sort. The only work around i find so far is to put a pseudo-element on  "li::before" and use it just for onclick, but im not satisfied...

Comment: @degeaba I have updated my post, and added a codepen link for you to see things in action.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ji_in_coding example i figure out how to do https://codepen.io/Nindos/pen/YOXdzW

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.item).addClass('ui-being-dragged');
  },
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    //$(ui.item).removeClass('ui-being-dragged');
  }
});

$("#sortable>li").on('click',function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('ui-being-dragged')){
        alert('JUST CLICK');
    }else{$(this).removeClass('ui-being-dragged');}
});
```